# Add attributes to TextBoxFor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this :

```
<input type="text" name="myInput" id="myInput" class="myClass" data-a-sign="€ " data-a-dec="," data-a-sep=".">
```

In Razor :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyValue, new { @class="myClass", id = "myInput", name="myInput" })
```

How can I add : data-a-sign, data-a-dec, data-a-sep ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By using underscores:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(
    m => m.MyValue, 
    new { 
        @class="myClass", 
        id = "myInput", 
        name = "myInput",
        data_a_sign = "€",
        data_a_dec = ",",
        data_a_sep = "."
    }
)
```

ASP.NET MVC helpers will transform the underscores to dashes when generating the markup.